# Most effective way to turn Observable into ObservableValue/Binding/EventStream?

Tags: java, javafx, reactive-programming, rx-java, reactfx

I will be using RxJava and ReactFX more heavily, but what I am trying to understand is how to reconcile the two since ReactFX does not have an RxJava dependency, so how can the two talk to each other within the same monad? This is especially the case for bridging between JavaFX's `ObservableValue`, RxJava's `Observable`, and ReactFX's `StreamEvent` without a lot of boilerplate.

I want to compose my core business logic with RxJava since they won't always be backing JavaFX applications. But I want the JavaFX UI to use `ReactFX` and utilize the `EventStream`. So my question is what is the most effective way to turn an `EventStream` into an `Observable`, and an `Observable` into an `EventStream`, `Binding`, or `ObservableValue`? I know I could just use RxJava across the board but I want to leverage ReactFX's Platform thread safety and conveniences...

```
//DESIRE 1- Turn EventStream into Observable in the same monad
Observable<Foo> obs = EventStream.valuesOf(fooObservableValue).toObservable();

//Desire 2- Turn Observable into ObservableValue, Eventstream, or Binding
Binding<Foo> obsVal = Observable.create(...).toBinding();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To turn ReactFX `EventStream` into RxJava `Observable`:

```
Observable<Foo> toRx(EventStream<Foo> es) {
    PublishSubject<Foo> sub = PublishSubject.create();
    es.subscribe(sub::onNext);
    return sub;
}
```

To turn RxJava `Observable` into ReactFX `EventStream`:

```
EventStream<Foo> fromRx(Observable<Foo> obs) {
    EventSource<Foo> es = new EventSource<>();
    obs.subscribe(foo -> Platform.runLater(() -> es.push(foo)));
    return es;
}
```

Notice the `Platform.runLater(...)` in the latter case. This makes the resulting `EventStream` emit events on the JavaFX application thread.

Also note that we are ignoring the `Subscription`s returned from the `subscribe` methods in both cases. This is fine if you are establishing the binding for the lifetime of your application. If, on the other hand, the binding between them should be short-lived, in the first case, you would have your RxJava component expose the `Subject`, your ReactFX component expose the `EventStream`, and then do `subscribe`/`unsubscribe` as necessary. Similarly for the second case.

Comment: By the way, I am finding this does not work in the TableView TableColumn cellValueFactory. Some weird stuff happens with the FX thread and the schedulers. Not quite sure what to do about this.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with ReactFX, but looking at the API I could deduce these conversions:

```
public static <T> Observable<T> toObservable(EventStream<? extends T> es) {
    return Observable.create(child -> {
        Subscription s = es.subscribe(child::onNext);
        child.add(Subscriptions.create(s::unsubscribe));
    });
}
public static <T> EventStream<T> toEventStream(Observable<? extends T> o) {
    return new EventStream<T>() {
        final Vector<Consumer<? super T>> observers = new Vector<>();
        @Override
        public void addObserver(Consumer<? super T> observer) {
            observers.add(observer);
        }

        @Override
        public void removeObserver(Consumer<? super T> observer) {
            observers.remove(observer);
        }
        @Override
        public Subscription subscribe(Consumer<? super T> subscriber) {
            addObserver(subscriber);

            rx.Subscriber<T> s = new rx.Subscriber<T>() {
                @Override
                public void onNext(T t) {
                    subscriber.accept(t);
                }
                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    removeObserver(subscriber);
                }
                @Override
                public void onCompleted() {
                    removeObserver(subscriber);
                }
            };
            o.subscribe(s);

            return () -> {
                s.unsubscribe();
                removeObserver(subscriber);
            };
        }
    };
}
```

Both should give you unsubscription capability, although ReactFX doesn't support synchronous unsubscription and I don't really see if EventStream can be used as a hot or cold observable. I couldn't access Binding so can't help you there.